# Help please!!! Screw won't loosen?

Tags: screws

I have a screw that won't loosen completely it spins to the right and the left but ends up tightening again. I think it has a certain point where it'll just let go and be able to be pulled out but I don't know how to do that. It's not a regular screw that I've ever seen it has a hexagon deep inside but it has space for a regular Phillips screw driver and a flat head.

Comment: More information will be needed in order to be able to provide suggestions. A picture or two would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Is this screw part of a furniture assembly?  What you describe sounded like a cam-lock nut, like can be seen here: http://www.swedishfurnitureparts.com/products/ikea-cam-lock-nut-103433
If that's it, then it won't actually retract, you just align it so the adjacent part can be removed.  There should be a dot or indicator showing you which way it needs to be aligned.

Comment: It's pretty much an answer, though not clear if it's the right one until we get further info.